# Iframe dialogs must be called with a session key

Tags: facebook, session, iframe, dialog

I'm trying to call `FB.ui` to make a wall post in an iframe. However, when I set display to iframe, I get a `102 error "Iframe dialogs must be called with a session key"`. I have an access token, I'm logged in, everything else seems to be working (I can even post directly to the stream with PHP without bringing up the prompt). Any ideas?

**PHP:**

```php
require_once('facebook.php');
define('APP_ID',"276733022359677");
define('APP_SECRET',"xxxx");
$my_url = URI_B."/spider/";

$config = array();
$config['appId'] = APP_ID;
$config['secret'] = APP_SECRET;
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$fbid = $facebook->getUser();
if($fbid == 0){
    $scope = "";
    header("Location: ".$facebook->getLoginUrl($scope));
}
```

**Javascript:**

```js
FB.init({appId: "276733022359677", status: true, cookie: true});
function publish() {
    var obj = {
        display: 'iframe',
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'http://discussiontopic.comyr.com/spider/',
        name: 'Test',
        caption: 'Test Caption',
        description: 'This is a test.'
    };

    FB.ui(obj);
}
```

I also get an unspecified error at the login page (if redirected there to log in).

Answer (score 2):

If you have the user's access token, specify it as a parameter to the `FB.ui` call:

```js
var obj = {
    display: 'iframe',
    access_token: '<%= $access_token %>',
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'http://discussiontopic.comyr.com/spider/',
    name: 'Test',
    caption: 'Test Caption',
    description: 'This is a test.'
};
```